# PHP undefined variable error when dynamically including files

Tags: php

I wrote a tiny function called load, to include multiple file at once, instead of using multiple include statements. Things work fine, except when I echo a variable, I keep getting the `Undefined variable` error.

Here are the files. The file that runs everything is `inc-main.php`. That's where the `Undefined variable` error is thrown on `line 9`.

Any help on this can be solved? I don't get any file include errors which means the file are being included. The only problem is with the Variables.

**load.php**

```
<?php

$paths = array(
    'iNa'=>ROOT.'/test/inc-a.php',
    'iNb'=>ROOT.'/test/inc-b.php',
);

function load($files) {
    global $paths;
    $files = func_get_args();
    foreach($files as $file) {
        echo ($paths[$file]).'<br>';
        require_once($paths[$file]);
    }
}

?>
```

**inc-a.php**

```
<?php

$name = 'Donald';
$city = 'Duckberg';

?>
```

**inc-b.php**

```
<?php

$location = 'San Francisco';

?>
```

**inc-main.php**

```
<?php

define('ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

include(ROOT.'/test/load.php');

load('iNa','iNb');

echo 'Hello, my name is '.$name.', and I live in '.$city.'!'; /* Line 9 */

?>
```

Comment: As you are doing the `require` inside a function, you are putting all of the variables in the scope of that function.

Comment: Ok. So what needs to be done here to solve this. I cannot declare every variable as global since they differ in each file...

Comment: Just write multiple `require` statements, is there a reason why you don't want to?

Comment: There are many. That's the reason I turned to this approach.

Comment: Only way to solve this (without going down totally ridiculous paths that involve `eval` or worse), would probably be to eliminate the function then. Specify what files you want to load in a global variable, and then embed your `load.php` _after_ that, so that it has access to the variable, and can loop over it directly (without that loop being wrapped into a function.)